# Enterprise Library Data access MySQL integration

Tags: c#, mysql, enterprise-library

Is it possible to use MySQL with the data access application block?

The existing providers there don't include mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the MSEL DAAB with MySQL. Thus, you need to configure a GenericDatabase using your own MySQL DataProvider. Otherwise, you may benefit of other CodePlex contributions with a provider for MySQL at this [link](http://www.codeplex.com/entlibcontrib).